# Process an element anywhere in the xml document with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a `xml` file that is basically the data of an article. I want to transform it using `xslt`.

**My question:** how do I process an element through xslt anywhere, at **any depth** in the xml document?

My research led me to find about the identity template but my attempt to use it proved unfructful. Here is something I tried:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="em">
blabla
</xsl:template>
```

But it didn't replace the `em` content with blabla.

I also found out that validating an element anywhere is not something possible to do with a `xsd` schema. But I hope the answer is different for `xslt`.

Minimal Working Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>
    <foo>text <em>italics</em> anything</foo>
    <tag>text <foo><em>italics</em> stuff</foo></tag>
</doc>
```

I would like for instance to have `<em>foo</em>` replaced by `<it>foo</it>` or `\emph{foo}` (while of course doing other transformation on the document).

Comment: If your `xsl:template match="em"` did not match and process the `em` elements in your sample then your sample is different from the one you posted and probably has the elements in some namespace.  Your approach is correct and should work for the sample you have shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XSLT already works as requested.

Here's a complete example that replaces `em` with `it`:

### XML in

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>
    <foo>text <em>italics</em> anything</foo>
    <tag>text <foo><em>italics</em> stuff</foo></tag>
</doc>
```

### XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="em">
    <it>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </it>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### XML out

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doc>
    <foo>text <it>italics</it> anything</foo>
    <tag>text <foo>
         <it>italics</it> stuff</foo>
   </tag>
</doc>
```

Comment: Thanks. I now realize my MWE doesn't capture my problem, as your MWE works, but my xslt on my real file is more complicated and doesn't work despite using that identity template. I'll ask a question soon again if I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't explained in what respect the solution you tried wasn't what you wanted, but it sounds like you've got the right idea. You can modify the identity template to remove the `<copy>` statement and it will then just loop through all elements depth-first, matching any of the desired element to your specific template. If that isn't what you want, please be more specific in your question.

Comment: I want the `em` be processed at any depth of the tree, not just as the children of the parent.

Comment: That's what the identity template does; it invokes itself on every element matched, which then invokes templates on every child element